# Mootools Numeric Textox

Tags: javascript, mootools, numeric-textbox

I am looking for **numeric textbox** control based on mootools framework.

i'd be grateful if someone help me to find or implement this control.

thank you .
Alimz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also easily write this yourself.

```
var isNumberKey = function(e){
    if (e.code > 31 && (e.code < 48 || e.code > 57)) 
        return false;   
    return true;
}

var isBackSpaceKey: function(e){
    return e.code == 8;
}

var isArrowKey: function(e) {
    return e.code >= 37 && e.code <= 40;
}

var inputs = $$('.width-input', '.height-input');
inputs.addEvent('keyup', function(e){
  if (!isNumberKey(e) && !isBackSpaceKey(e) && !isArrowKey(e)) 
            e.stop();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you mean but:

[mootools formcheck](http://mootools.floor.ch/en/demos/formcheck/) is a class-based semantic solution which relies on css classes to define a ruleset for each input field. For example:

```
<input class="validate['required','number']" />
```

Pretty flexible and pretty cool, thumbs up from me and the idea of a hash based ruleset within the element’s class is just great.

[mootools iMask](http://zendold.lojcomm.com.br/imask/) by Fabio Nagao is something similar to formcheck, but it takes matters further. iMask actually attaches itself to the input element and helps the user populate their data as per a pre-set ‘mask’. The mask is just a patterned format that cannot be broken. In reality, it allows you to ask your user to enter really complex data blocks, for example, you can have a field that contains (+NN)-NNN-AZ, hyphens, brackets and plus sign included. The end-user can only enter numerics or alpha characters in their designated places. Check it out, it’s really impressive